# Topshelf service and Wix Installer

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, wix, topshelf

We develop a pack of windows services and used topshelf, which helped us to write them with easy. But now we implement an installer for them and faced a problem: Wix installs our services incorrectly. 
As mentioned [here](https://github.com/Topshelf/Topshelf/issues/145), the problem is because class, implementing Installer base class is somewhere in Topshelf and isn't found by util Wix uses to install service. We cannot write installers for each service and neither do want to implement our own custom actions to work with services (make registry entries for them, check if they are installed and so on). So, what can we do to deal with this problem?

Comment: You can try [Microsoft Installers](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9abe329c-9bba-44a1-be59-0fbf6151054d/view/Discussions/5), as there are some issues with WIX and InstallSheild

Comment: @stuartd, No, because i'm not able to write installer for each service.. Finally i solved problem implicitly by calling exe via command-prompt

Comment: Wix can be used to install topshelf service. You just have to make sure that service name in wix file _exactly_ match service name in call to topshelf's SetServiceName().

Comment: Vasily, could you share your wxs file in an answer? Also, did you have to make any code changes in your Topshelf service? Thanks!

Comment: @Alex Voskresenskiy Please share your solution as an answer.